# Перенос файла в С++

Tags: c++

Я написал код:

```
MoveFile("путь1", "путь2");
```

Как сделать, чтобы программа просила у меня ввести путь и вставила в "путь1" и в "путь2".
т.е я ввожу
           c:/desktop
           c:/documents and settings

и в итоге программа получила:
           MoveFile("c:/desktop", "c:/documents and settings");
и перенесла файлы
Можете помочь?

Comment: книги по си/с++ в помощь

Comment: спасибо, ответ "очень помог"! Думаю если бы в книге нашел ответ, то меня бы тут не было

Comment: Если так уж сложно, вот мой ответ: нужны две строковые переменные, в первую считывается первый путь, соответственно во вторую - второй (с помощью функций scanf или gets если си или через cin если с++). Далее вызывается MoveFile с именами переменных в качестве параметров. В чем сложность?

Comment: ничего не понял

Comment: @insolor @mikillskegg я могу присвоить переменным, моя единственная проблема в кавычках, т.е я могу сделать так, точнее умею

cin >> a;
где ввожу a например: c:/desktop, но так как она будет без кавычек, она не возмется за путь к файлу, вот в этом проблема, как сделать, чтобы при ввождении кавычки уже стояли, а текст введенный был между кавычками. А может и есть другой путь, только я его не знаю.

Comment: может нужно экранировать кавычки?

Comment: т.е? можно поподробней?

Comment: "\\"Hello, World!\\"" - строка, которая содержит "Hello, World!" (с кавычками). Кстати в ОС семейства Windows в адресах используется не слэш '/' а бэкслэш '\\', который в C++ выглядит как '\\\\' (два подряд).

PS `path = "\\"C:\\\\desktop\\\\""`

Comment: Зачем вам кавычки?! Это когда вы в явном виде передаете функции MoveFile("путь1","путь2") то заключаете их в кавычки, так как инициализация строковых переменных производится в кавычках! Но если же вы будете передавать в функцию переменные (строчки с путями), вам не надо вводить никаких кавычек! Просто считываете с клавиатуры в переменную way1: C:\desktor и передаете эту переменную в функцию!

Comment: @navi1893, напиши в вопросе проблемный кусок кода, я уже сам ничего не понимаю

Comment: я хочу присвоить переменной адрес, а при этом эта переменная какого типа должна быть? char? да и так будет:
  
  cin >>  a >> endl;
  cin >>  b >> endl; 
 { MoveFile("\a\" , "\b\");

а а,b какого типа должны быть при этом?

Answer (score 4):

Я так понимаю, MoveFile - это некая функция, осуществляющая копирование файла. Ну так вот такой код, например.

```
char path1[100], path2[100];
cout << "Введите источник" << endl;
cin.getline (path1, 100);
cout << "Введите назначение" << endl;
cin.getline (path2, 100);
cout << "path1 = " << path1 << endl;
cout << "path2 = " << path2 << endl;   
MoveFile (path1, path2);
```

Comment: код прошел, но он ничего не делает =Р

Comment: Слегка дополнил код. Если будет печатать введенные пути, значит, все с кодом нормально. Нужно смотреть в функцию MoveFIle.

И еще. Вы хотите так вот одним махом перенести все содержимое директории Desktop. Не получится. Так можно копировать только отдельные файлы. Для копирования директорий все сложнее. Пока подумайте о копировании одного файла

Comment: нет, я это ради примера так написал, я вот пишу так после включения программы:

c:\\123.txt
c:\\NewFolder

но он не переносит, знаете причину?

Comment: А сама эта папка New Folder существует? Кстати, проверили, в функцию нормально передаются пути? 

В общем, смотрите внутрь функции MoveFile

Comment: Нужно явно указывать имя конечного файла: `c:\123.txt c:\NewFolder\123.txt`

Comment: да, существует, и это проверил, пути выдаются, так в чем проблема не могу понять

Comment: @insolor, может, и так. Надо разбираться с функцией

Comment: все! @insolor вы правы, спасибо всем кто помог! надо было конечный файл указать )

Comment: У меня с явным укзанием имен переносит. Еще в MSDN сказано, что эта функция может переименовывать (переносить) папки вместе с содержимим, но это значит что `с:\Desktop` будет переименована в `c:\Documents and Settings`

Answer (score 1):

```
char a[100],b[100];
cin >> a >> b;
MoveFile(a, b);
```

Кавычки не нужны.

Comment: выдает 4 ошибок =Р

там где cin >> a,b --> 1) expected primary-expression before "char" 
                     2) expected `;' before "char"

Comment: Зачем после  cin >> a писать >> endl ? Вы хоть подумайте, что при этом происходит?

Comment: @mikillskegg, так лучше?

Comment: Лучше. Только учтите, что cin>> считывает и отправляет в строку массив символов до первого пробела. Лучше использовать метод getline, как я написал.

Comment: Если когда-нибудь придется писать на с++, учту)